# Is it possible to configure git mergetool to avoid .orig for a given merge tool?

Tags: git, git-config

Some parameters to configure git mergetool seem to be global and can't be set up on a per tool basis.

I just want to make sure that setting `keepBackup = false` can be set on `[mergetool]`, but not on `[mergetool "yourtool"]`

As far as I know this will work:

```
[mergetool]
    prompt = false
    keepBackup = false
```

But this won't:

```
[mergetool "semanticmerge"]
    cmd = C:/Users/pablo/AppData/Local/PlasticSCM4/semanticmerge/semanticmergetool.exe -d \"$LOCAL\" -s \"$REMOTE\" -b \"$BASE\" -r \"$MERGED\" -a
    trustExitCode = true
    **keepBackup = false**
```

It's correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that [Charles Bailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19563/charles-bailey) introduced 5 years ago a *global* settings instead of a per-mergetool settings, in [commit 44c36d (February 2008, git 1.5.5+)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/44c36d1ccc9a40bfb31910dfd7e18d59fa8be502).
It wasn't documented properly before [commit d1cc46 (July 2010, git 1.7.1.2)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d1cc4621eda62222fbc929a7f65c89b6be678c2e).

So a `keepBackup` in `mergetool.xxx` wouldn't be correct indeed.

That would be a good topic for patching git.

Comment: Thanks. It is not the best solution since you might want to have different options per tool.